# Set http 1.1 as default libcurl linux

Tags: r, http, curl, libcurl

I am developing a R Project that makes some http requests to Google Trends through GTrends library. However when I make the requests I get this error:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle): Stream error in the HTTP/2 framing layer.
```

I've searched a solution and I've found that is needed to disable http2 in curl as described here: [solution](https://github.com/jeroen/curl/issues/156). However that provided solution `handle_setopt(handle, http_version = 0L)` does not work, at least for me. Curl documentation says that: **Since 7.47.0, the curl tool enables HTTP/2 by default for HTTPS connections**. So, does anyone know how can I set http 1.1 as default in order to avoid this error? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and curl 7.58.0. I appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Default* means what is used unless you set another version. Thus, you setting 1.1 as protocol version desired will override the default libcurl itself would use.

That said, don't confuse curl the tool with libcurl the library. If you use the library, the command line tool's default choices should not matter to you!